# Non - Similar Triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

State whether the following pair of triangles are similar or not :

[image]

Using the Law of Cosines we can obtain the values of $AC$ and $ED,$ and thereby show that there are no three pairs of corresponding sides for which their ratios are same.

But this is an exercise question taken from a chapter before the introduction of trigonometry.

Thus I'll have to resort to showing that neither of these two conditions hold viz.

(i) Their corresponding angles are equal

(ii) Their corresponding sides are proportional

I can't seem to figure out any other elementary way apart from using the Law of Cosines

Comment: I think If $AC$ was $3$ instead of $BC$ these triangles were similar but now they are not.

Comment: If you do not go by their given shapes, take a case $AC = 3, DE = 6$ and both are isosceles triangles with $80^0, 80^0, 20^0$ angles, they are similar and you have to apply sine / cos law or some argument to show whether those angles are possible in a triangle with sides $6, 6, 5$.

Comment: @MathLover I checked. Such Triangles do not exist. The solution manual says that these triangles are NOT similar. It is obvious if I am allowed to invoke the Law of Cosines, but unfortunately - I cannot.

Comment: Yes @BijeshK.S I know such triangles do not exist. It was just an example to show that it was not obvious to confirm whether they were similar or not unless we assume (based on the shape given) the other two angles are less than $80^0$ in both triangles.

Comment: Definitely not obvious. To show that the side lengths are incompatible with an 80-80-20 triangle, it seems like you'd need to know something about $\sin 80$. Then there is also the possibiliy that $|AC|=2.5\cdot \frac56$, which is also not obviously incompatible with the angle..